# Salesforce CPQ inside Customer Community / Ecommerce site

Tags: customer-community, experience-cloud, cpq, cpq-plugins, cpq-api

My client is currentlty using a third party ecommerce site for pricing/simulation, and using Salesforce CPQ separately.

He would like to replace the current custom pricer/simulator by CPQ, by adding it inside the third party portal.

The goal is therefore to allow external users (customers) to simulate price and generate quote with CPQ, but from a third party ecommerce portal.

I am wondering what would be the best solution :

1. Use [CPQ for Experience Builder Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_lightning_comm_parent.htm&type=5) :

- But how to embed the community inside the ecommerce 3rd party site ?

2. Use [Salesforce CPQ API](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_cpq_nc.htm&release=230&type=5) to query Salesforce CPQ capabilities from the ecommerce site ?

Does anyone already faced that use case ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: General questions regarding [integrating Salesforce with 3rd party systems](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) usually need a lot of detailed information to be able to be answered. Could you, as a starting point, add to your question precise requirements as to what this integration is supposed to achieve? What data in which direction, what frequency, what changes are envisaged for end users etc.? What are you aiming at?

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your answer. The final goal is to allow external users (customers) to simulate price and generate quote with CPQ, but from a third party ecommerce portal. This should be synchronous, that's why I consider using "CPQ for Experience Builder" and then embed that community inside the ecommerce third party portal (Can we easily embed a community page inside a third party portal ?), or use CPQ API, and consume these APIs from the third party ecommerce portal (But how to authenticate exernal users (With integration user ?)

Comment: Please add to your question rather than answering comments with comments. You say "The final goal ... from a third party ecommerce portal." I thought this already exists?! And please make clear what you mean by "should be synchronous". Simultaneous simulation?!

Comment: Hi, just amended the initial question. By synchronous, I mean that customers will need to interrogate CPQ engine.